Square root of an Anosov diffeomorphism
Let $T\colon \mathbb T^d\to\mathbb T^d$ be an Anosov diffeomorphism (that is, the tangent bundle splits into invariant stable and unstable bundles; the restriction of $DT$ to the unstable bundle is uniformly expanding; the restriction of $DT$ to the stable bundle is uniformly contracting).
Suppose also that $T=S^2$ where $S$ is continuous.
Must $S$ be Anosov?
A positive answer is given in this MSE post in the case where you assume that $S$ is a volume-preserving diffeomorphism. I'm hoping to get the same conclusion under weaker conditions. In my case I only care about $d=2$, and know that $S$ is Hölder continuous and area-preserving.
